# How can one get more than 12 commands in Compiz->Commands?

Tags: compiz, keyboard, shortcuts

How can one get more than 12 comands in Compiz->Comands?

It's mainly for screen bindings.

Answer (score 2):

`System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`

That allows you to add conceivably an infinite amount of key bindings.

Comment: Im sorry, it's exclusively for screen bindings.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Compiz will accept this, but these settings are stored in gconf.

```
gconf-editor
```

Run that, then navigate to `/apps/compiz/plugins/commands/allscreens/options/`

Try right-click -> New Key

Name it `command12` and make it of type `string`  For value, put the command you want to run

Add keys named

- `run_command12_button`
- `run_command12_edge`
- `run_command12_key`

Also of type string

---

For edge, you can set any of the following:

- TopLeft
- Top
- TopRight
- Left
- Right
- BottomLeft
- BottomRight
- Bottom

If you want it to make it able to activate on top or bottom, put it like `Top|Bottom`

---

For button, if you want it to activate when you left click on the top edge, that'd look like `<TopEdge>Button1` or if you wanted it to be for Ctrl+Alt+Click, that'd be `<Control><Alt>Button1`

Extrapolate from there

---

For key, you're probably getting the pattern.  `<Super>Q` to make it Win+Q, etc.

---

I have no evidence that Compiz will read past command11, but if it just reads everything in that part of GConf, then this could work.